# Web site to smartphone application

Tags: android, iphone, blackberry, mobile

How best way to carry the website for a smartphones application?

Is better to build an entire application or just an interface that performs http queries already available on the website?

There is a pattern?

Ps.: The application must to have maximum security in transactions

Comment: Security generally means not trusting anything not under you control, of which code running on the device tends to be an example, so that points to keeping most of the functionality on the server and using a simple client, perhaps just a (skinned?) browser.  Conversely, performance (especially with regard to network delays or outage) and infrastructure cost can sometimes point to putting more functionality on the device.  The easiest place to start may be to make a list of what is wrong with accessing your site from the device's current browser.

Comment: Let's be real: The CIA needs "maximum security". You do not.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what "maximum security" means, but the principal tool for converting a web application into a smartphone app is [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/).

Comment: The "maximun securtity" means that Most transactions will be with SSL.

Comment: Yea, you'd use SSL just like you do now.

Comment: My understanding of the PhoneGap is a generic application, as we have a development team, we are looking for patterns and best practices to make our development.

Comment: Sencha Touch uses MVC, which works nicely with PhoneGap. I can't  understand your question very well, so it's difficult to figure out exactly what you want.

Comment: the idea is similar a banking app, where my customer can consult your data similarly to what they do on the website